Windows 11 - How to open a Terminal with Admin privilege from current folder in File Explorer?
In Windows 10 (I think?) I could launch a Terminal/Powershell from File Explorer with or without admin privilege. I can't find that option for Windows 11 anymore. Is it still possible?

If you right click in File Explorer, you can select Open in Terminal in the current folder.

If you Shift + right click, you can select Open in Terminal or Open PowerShell window here in the current folder.

You can also use Alt + F and select Open in Terminal

If you want PowerShell to run as adminisrator by default, you can change this in the Terminal settings for the PowerShell profile.


This is one workaround I will be using though I don't really like that my Terminal now always run with admin permission.

@LukeVo You can also check here for some workarounds to restore the ribbon in File Explorer: https://www.elevenforum.com/t/restore-classic-file-explorer-with-ribbon-in-windows-11.620/. Some still work in 23H2 and above. This will allow the old Alt+F.S.R/A shortcut to choose between PowerShell in admin or not.

Thanks, I also found https://www.elevenforum.com/t/add-open-in-windows-terminal-admin-context-menu-in-windows-11.581/ to add the context menu as well. The above comment solution only opens (the system's) PowerShell instead of Terminal.
